# No almacena el correo aleatorio generado en otra clase

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

estoy realizando scrip para un test de una pagina, tengo una clase que genera un correo aleatorio, pero al intentar reutilizarlo en otra clase, no lo pasa (queda como null).
En esta clase se genera, en randomEmail = ApiOperations.generateRandomEmail(); y deberia almacenarlo en getRandomEmail()

```
package pom;

import api.ApiOperations;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.Duration;
public class RegisterPage extends BasePage {
public DemoAccountPage demoAccountPage;
private String randomEmail;

public RegisterPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    this.demoAccountPage = new DemoAccountPage(driver);
}

private final By inputForenames = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"name\"]");
private final By inputLastnames = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lastname\"]");
private final By inputEmail = By.xpath("//input[@id='email']");
private final By inputPhone = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"phoneNumber\"]");
private final By inputPassword = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]");
private final By inputConfirmPassword = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"confirmPassword\"]");
private final By btnIagree = By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-auth/section/section[2]/app-sign-up/form/section[2]/section/div/section[1]/label[1]/span");
private final By btnIdeclare = By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-auth/section/section[2]/app-sign-up/form/section[2]/section/div/section[2]/label[1]/span");
private final By btnRegister =
        By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-auth/section/section[2]/app-sign-up/form/section[3]/button");
By TxtEmailVerification = By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-auth/section/section[2]/app-confirmation-email/section/section");

public void enterForenames(String forenames) {
    type(inputForenames, forenames);
}
public void enterLastnames(String lastnames) {
    type(inputLastnames, lastnames);
}
public void clickIAgree() { click(btnIagree); }
public void clickIDeclare() { click(btnIdeclare); }
public void clickRegister() {
    click(btnRegister);
}
public void sendEmail (String email){
    type(inputEmail, email);
}
public void sendPhone(String phone) {
    type(inputPhone, phone);
}
public void sendPass (String password){
    type(inputPassword, password);
}
public void sendConfirmPass (String confirmPassword){
    type(inputConfirmPassword, confirmPassword);
}

 public String getRandomEmail() {
    return randomEmail;
}

public void registerUserAndVerifyEmail(String forenames, String lastnames, String password, String confirmPassword, String phone) {
     randomEmail = ApiOperations.generateRandomEmail();
    enterForenames(forenames);
    enterLastnames(lastnames);
    sendEmail(randomEmail);
    sendPhone(phone);
    sendPass(password);
    sendConfirmPass(confirmPassword);
    clickIAgree();
    clickIDeclare();
    //System.out.println(randomEmail);   //Activate if it is necessary to know the email

}
}
```

y en esta clase lo manda a llamar

```
package pom;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DemoAccountPage extends BasePage {
private RegisterPage registerPage;


public DemoAccountPage(WebDriver driver, RegisterPage registerPage) {
    super(driver);
    this.registerPage = registerPage;

}

public DemoAccountPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public void setRandomEmail() {
        String randomEmail = registerPage.getRandomEmail();
        if (randomEmail != null) {
            System.out.println("Correo Aleatorio en DemoAccountPage: " + randomEmail);
            
            By inputEmail = By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-auth/section/section[2]/app-sign-in/form/section[2]/div[1]/div/input");
            type(inputEmail, randomEmail);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se ha establecido el correo aleatorio en DemoAccountPage.");
        }
    }
}
```

En mi step lo llama asi

```
@When("Access with validate email {string}, and password {string}")
public void accessWithValidateEmail(String randomEmail,String password) {
    demoAccountPage.setRandomEmail();
    homePage.enterPassword(password);

}
```

pero en consola me arroja el mensaje "No se ha establecido el correo aleatorio en DemoAccountPage." lo cual me indica que randomEmail esta vacio, no se paso el valor, como lo puedo corregir?
Gracias de antemano por sus comentarios.